# Cannot access props field from Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to ReactJS, but I'd like to create simple domain with ability to login and logout. I store user credentials in AsyncStorage. Here is my index.js:

```
..
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
..

class Index extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
                    <Route path='/welcome' component={Welcome}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root')); registerServiceWorker();
```

On **Home** page, there is a Button which moves to login page:

```
<Button color="primary" onClick={() => {this.props.history.push("/login")}}>Sign In</Button>
```

**Login** component contains form, which on submit calls given method:

```
this.props.history.push("/welcome");
```

Finally on **Welcome** page I have following *button*:

```
class Welcome extends Component {

    handleLogout() {
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello!</h1>
                <Button onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Welcome);
```

I'd like to say that every component (**Home**,**Login**,**Welcome**) is wrapped in withRouter component, but once I click *button* on Welcome page, error occurs:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Change `handleLogout() {` to `handleLogout = () => {`.

Comment: @Dan It works. Could you post it as an answer, so I can confirm it, and maybe explain why it works and what's the difference between my broken version? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, the value of `this` isn't determined until a function is actually called. And since onClick is something that happens asynchronously, handleLogout will be called with no context, which means that `this` is bound to the window object in non-strict mode, or undefined in strict mode. You're apparently in non-strict mode, so `this.props.history.push` is the same as `window.props.history.push`. `window.props` is undefined, resulting in the error.

There are several ways to fix this:

1) Use an arrow function in render. Arrow functions have the same value of `this` as when they were declared, so `this` will equal your component

```
<Button onClick={(event) => this.handleLogout(event)}/>
```

2) Explicitly bind your handleLogout function in your constructor. This creates a new function, for which the value of `this` is locked in.

```
class Welcome extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
  }

  handleLogout() {
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }
  //etc
}
```

3) If you're using the [babel-plugin-transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/) plugin, define handleLogout as an arrow function:

```
class Welcome extends Component {
  handleLogout = () => {
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }
  //etc
}
```

Comment: So, what I understand is I have to bind context of Button with context of Welcome component?

Comment: Close, but it's more about the function than the Button. The function needs to be called with the context of the Welcome component. The button will never know anything about the Welcome component.

Answer (score 2):

It's to do with how `this` is define. You're defining your `handleLogout` in the context of your component but then you are passing it into a different context and executing it there. `this` will be different in that context hence why props is undefined.

Essentially, if you are passing functions into a different context (and you need to access something from `this` such as props or state you need to bind the function to the components version of `this`. You can do this in one of two common ways

In the constructor of your component:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
}
```

or by defining your method using an arrow function (this 'auto binds') - but this method is not fully ratified so will most likely require a babel polyfill:

```
handleLogout = () => { // function code }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really common problem people have in react, you're not passing the proper scope down to the handler function. So, when handleLogout is called, the scope (represented by 'this') doesn't include props. You need to bind 'this' to that handler function before it's passed down to a child component. You can do this either by using an arrow function when you give the function to the Button, (an arrow function automatically passes scope down):

```
<Button
    onClick={() => this.handleLogout()}
>
    Logout
</Button>
```

or you can bind this to the handler function in a constructor:

```
class Welcome extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
    }
```

Whenever you see an error in React that indicates props isn't defined, 'this' should be the first thing you check. (pun intended!)

Answer (score 0):

You should use react-router withRouter HOC like this:

[image]
then you can read history from `this.props`